Flutter - WebSocketException
I am implementing socket in flutter and I have connected socket successfully. But when I use socket.emit() shows below Exception.

Exception :  WebSocketException: Connection to 'https://dev-api.unitywebinar.com:0/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket#' was not upgraded to websocket.

Code:
IO.Socket? _socket = IO.io(
        "URL",
        IO.OptionBuilder()
            .setTransports(['websocket'])
            // .disableAutoConnect()
            .enableAutoConnect()
            // .enableForceNew()
            .build());

    _socket.onConnectError((data) {
      _socket.disconnect();
      print("onConnectError");
      print("ERROR ==========> $data");
    });

    _socket.onConnect((data) {
      print("onConnect");
      print("_socket.connected; ${_socket.connected}");

    _socket.emit("EMIT_NAME", (data) {
        log(data);
      },);

I have connected this socket successfully but when I use emit it shows WebSocketException: Connection to 'URL' was not upgraded to websocket.
